An expression for $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-p x} x^{q-1}(1+a x)^{-\nu} dx$ seems wrong
I found the following equation in the book "Table of integrals, series, and products by I.S. Gradshteyn and I.M. Ryzhik 7th edition"  page348 -3.383:
$$\begin{aligned} & \int_0^{\infty} e^{-p x} x^{q-1}(1+a x)^{-\nu} d x \\ & =\frac{\pi^2}{p^q \Gamma(\nu) \sin [\pi(q-\nu)]}\left[\left(\frac{p}{a}\right)^\nu \frac{L_{-\nu}^{\nu-q}\left(\frac{p}{a}\right)}{\sin (\pi \nu) \Gamma(1-q)}-\left(\frac{p}{a}\right)^q \frac{L_{-q}^{q-\nu}\left(\frac{p}{a}\right)}{\sin (\pi q) \Gamma(1-\nu)}\right]
\end{aligned}$$
with
$\operatorname{Re} q>0$, $\operatorname{Re} p>0$, $\operatorname{Re} a>0$, and $\nu \neq \pm 1, \pm 2, \ldots$.
I realize that when $q$ is an integer, the term $\sin(\pi q)$ becomes zero which seems like a problem. Besides, I do not know much about Laguerre polynomials, and I cannot find the formula for $L^a_n(x)$ when $n$ is a negative integer, even in this book.
Is this equation wrong?
Thanks!

What is the edition of the book and the equation number? In my books I see an expression for this integral through other special functions.

Is it 3.383 part 5 as per the 7th edition? (The page number is 397 for the PDF or 348 according to the text.)

@J.G.  yes, exactly

@Gec, I am using 7th edition, page348 -3.383 ,are we using the same book?

@Gec If you are using edition 8, the expression 3.383-5 is actually wrong which is corrected in the errata of the book. see https://www.mathtable.com/errata/gr8_errata.pdf

I use an old book published in 1963. In it the integral is expressed in terms of the Whittaker function associated with the degenerate hypergeometric function. There are also reference books "Integrals and Series" by Prudnikov, Brychkov and Marichev. The first volume contains expressions directly in terms of the degenerate hypergeometric function.

@Gec Thanks. that's really helpful.

Representations through more general function (Mathematica code) as: (a^(1 - q)*FoxH[{{{q - v, 1}, {0, 1}}, {}}, {{{-1 + q, 1}}, {}}, a/p])/(p*Gamma[v]).

Indeed, $q$ cannot be an integer for the same reason $\nu$ cannot be an integer. I have confirmed this with the editor of the book. In the case of computation when $q$ is an integer, we can use the formula given by another answer.

This is not an answer (too long for a comment)
I agree that the formula you gave (which I found) is quite confusing (at least to me).
Since comments can be volatile, I give here the results from Mathematica
$$I=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-p x} x^{q-1}(1+a x)^{-\nu} dx$$  Without any restriction, the provided result is, in terms of Kummer's confluent hypergeometric function,
$$I=a^{-\nu } p^{\nu -q} \Gamma (q-\nu ) \, _1F_1\left(\nu ;-q+\nu
   +1;\frac{p}{a}\right)+\frac{a^{-q} \Gamma (q) \Gamma (\nu -q) \, _1F_1\left(q;q-\nu   +1;\frac{p}{a}\right)}{\Gamma (\nu )}$$ if
$$(\Re(a)\geq 0\lor a\notin \mathbb{R})\land \Re(p)>0\land \Re(q)>0$$
If we use FullSImplify[%], appear the corresponding regularized confluent hypergeometric functions with a leading factor equal to $\pi  \csc (\pi  (q-\nu ))$ which is also problematic.
But assuming now $a>0$, $p>0$ and $q>0$, this can write
$$\large\color{blue}{a^{-q}\, \Gamma (q)\,\, U\left(q,q+1-\nu ,\frac{p}{a}\right)}$$ where $U(.)$ is  Tricomi's confluent hypergeometric function.
This has been numerically checked for $1,000$ random values of $(p,q,a,\nu)$
